# Activity has been destroyed (Fragment transaction commit + AsyncTask)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an activity in which when on its onCreate() state will executes a BackgroundTask (AsyncTask) that will return some data to the activity when its finished executing. When the data is received the activity adds a listFragment to itself through a Fragmenttransaction. The data received will be passed to the ListFragment for its adapter usage.

The issue is while the background task is running and then the screen orientation changes, the moment when the onPostExecute passes a data back to the activity and the activity tries to add the ListFragment the application crashes with the below error.

**java-lang-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstance**

Then i tried using `.commitAllowingStateLoss();`

with this i receive the error below

**Activiy has been Destroyed**

Please how else can i handle this flow process such that the screen orientation change doesn't crash the application.

Note that without a change in the screen orientation everything works perfect.
It only gets worse when there is a screen orientation change between when the activity is waiting for the background task to execute completely with its response data.

Comment: These two blog posts are related:  http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html and http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: Thanks Alex LockWood. I really now do have a full understanding of the process. I guess i will have to do execute the task on a fragment with setRetainInstance(true); well the good thing is there is not just one solution. understanding the process makes it simpler.. Thanks Man